# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on retriving NSData

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

In my app I am using the camera and photo library to get an UIImage...After picking the image I need to convert it to NSData and wants to pass this data to a method called addBlobToContainer:....but it gives the EXC_BAD_ACCESS....
How can I resolve this?

Here is my code for photo library...

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    image.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];
    imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image.image,1)];
    guid = [Guid randomGuid];
    NSLog(@"%@", guid.description);
    GUID = guid.description;
    NSLog(@"GUID===%@",GUID);
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     NSLog(@"STRIMAGEDATA===%@",imageData);

     if ([imageData length] != 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",imageData);
       [client addBlobToContainer:newcontainer blobName:GUID contentData:imageData contentType:@"application/octet-stream" withBlock:^(NSError *error)
       {
            if (error)
            {
            NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
            }
              else
              {
              NSLog(@"blob inserted suuccessfully…");
              imageURL = [serviceURL stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",GUID]];
              NSLog(@"IMAGEURL=%@",imageURL);
              }
          }];-->EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us declaration of `imageData`. Is it `strong` or `weak`?

Comment: Also the declarations of serviceURL and GUID.

Comment: Don't give your identifiers names like "image". Use the proper enum UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage not an string you define (could that be the issue?)

Comment: @7usam-Its not the issue

Comment: serviceURL and GUID are declared as NSString

Comment: @Sulthan NSData *imageData;

Comment: @Sulthan @property(nonatomic,retain) NSData *imageData;

Comment: You didn't answer the question for serviceURL and GUID.  How are those variables declared?

Comment: Those are the definitions. Synchronize them and in viewDidLoad you need to initialize them (or declare them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not accessing a property, you are accessing the variable behind the property. If you want the data to be automatically retained by the property, use property setters, e.g. `self.imageData = ...` instead of `imageData = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

self.imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image.image,1);